# CSS: Is there a way to target an element only when scroll bars are showing?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I had a vertical scroll frame with a black box centered in it but when testing it in Windows,  it was getting covered by scroll bars so I had to add more padding to it.  Now on windows, it looks fine as there is room for the scroll and the black box is centered ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkNmA.png ) .
But now on Macs since the scrollbars don't show, there is a ton of extra space on the right side before the dividing line shows ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIsNw.jpg ).
Is there any way to resolve this cleanly ?

Comment: Is disabling scrollbars entirely an option you want to make? You can't detect if a scrollbar is present with CSS. Your code really shouldn't have needed padding to avoid colliding with the scrollbar though. can you please post it?

Comment: if I can disable scrollbar for ALL, then that'd be fine!  I can do that for Windows' browsers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: Definitely consider that there really is no reason your page would need padding to avoid colliding with the scrollbar. The scrollbar makes the view-pane smaller, it doesn't lay over the top of it.

Comment: thanks!  This is exactly what I'm going to do

Answer (score 0):

You should try to detect if the window have a scrollbar with Javascript

```js
if ((window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth) > 0) {
  // Do some stuff like
  document.body.classList.add('withScrollbar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` of any scrolling element to determine if the scrollbars are showing. You can add a `clientWidth` and `scrollWidth` comparison if the container can also scroll horizontally.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.scroll-container')

if(element.clientHeight > element.scrollHeight) {
  element.classList.add('scroll-active')
}
else {
  element.classList.remove('scroll-active')
}
```